# Kubernetes: tomcat web context listener not called during deployment

Tags: windows, docker, kubernetes, tomcat, servletcontextlistener

Docker image:

```
   FROM tomcat:latest
   WORKDIR /usr/local/tomcat/webapps
   COPY my_webapp.war .
```

The webapp my_webapp.war contains a web listener:

```
@WebListener
public class MyContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        // do something, logging
    }
}
```

Build docker image:

```
docker build -t my_webapp:latest .
```

Start the container using docker, the web app is deployed and the MyContextListener is called (seen from logging).

```
  docker run -p 8091:8080 my_webapp:latest
```

But using k8s, the web app is deployed, but the MyContextListener is not called.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my_webapp
  labels:
    app: my_webapp
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my_webapp
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my_webapp
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: my_webapp:latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
```

Inspect the image (based on tomcat)

```
  docker inspect my_webapp:latest
```

Contains:

```
  "Cmd": [
            "catalina.sh",
            "run"
        ],
```

After overriding the image command by

```
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: my_webapp:latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
          command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "sleep 100000"]
```

> kubectl get pods

```
 my_webapp-846c7c99b5-s7kqt   1/1     Running   0          8h
```

Then shell into the container:

```
   kubectl exec -it my_webapp-846c7c99b5-s7kqt -- /bin/sh
   $ cd /usr/local/tomcat
   $ bin/catalina.sh run
```

The webapp is deployed and the web listener MyContextListener is called.

any difference between 1) k8s starting the container and running the command, and 2) manually run the command from a separated shell?